# Managing ScrollView and Input-Keyboard in react-native

Tags: react-native, android-softkeyboard, react-native-scrollview

The view between Account Name and Total is a FlatList.

**This Is The Normal View**

[image]

**This is What happens when i click one of the text view.**

[image]

Once clicked it seems unworkable.
It is completely fine if Total and everything below it is not there on the screen while keyboard in open.

Any Help on achieving the same would be highly appreciated.